# Batch file to change the wireless router password

Tags: batch, wireless-router

What would be the batch file commands to change the password of a wireless router at IP address 192.168.1.254?

I'd like to use it to turn off my wireless router at night and then turn it back on during the day.

Comment: Unless your wireless router is a Windows-based system *acting* as a wireless router, I doubt batch files will be of much help to you.  There may be some custom firmware plug-ins available which provide similar features to what you're looking for, but they more than likely won't be manageable by batch file commands and those features are probably not available in any stock firmwares.  In any case, there's still not nearly enough information here for anyone to provide a useful answer.

Comment: What has password changing to do with turning it on and off? Besides, once it is off, how would you turn it on again? Lastly, why turn it off? Routers (even cheap ones) really do work exceptionally well for a prolonged amount of time ...

Comment: At minimum, we'll need:  The OS & version on which you're wanting to use this "batch file", the make & model of your wireless router, and the name & version of the firmware that is running on that router.

Comment: @ldigas Turning the Wi-Fi router off at night (or whenever it's not in use) is considered a measure of security by some.  +1 to the rest of your comment, though.

Comment: I wonder if you could use CURL http://curl.haxx.se/ or AutoHotkeys http://www.autohotkey.com/ at the least.  I know a way not relying on a browser would be best.

Answer (score 4):

One approach,if low tech, is to could buy an inexpensive lamp timer and plug your router into it.  Set the time to shut off at night and power on in the morning